# Webpack dev server + React + Typescript wont inject assets after sources change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm starting to build a small app based on React, TypeScript and Webpack for building. I've followed this article: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html

All the sources are stored at GitHub repo: https://github.com/aszmyd/webpack-react-typescript-bug

**The issue:**

When i start webpack dev server for local development it properly serves files under `localhost:8080` and properly injects dynamic assets according to webpack configuration. **But** when i change something in source files, the rebuild gets fired and everything seems to be triggered properly but **the dynamic assets are not injected into index.html**. So after any change in source `tsx` files i get empty screen at `localhost:8080` because the `bundle.js` file **IS NOT INJECTED**

---

So steps to reporoduce:

1. Clone my test case repo: https://github.com/aszmyd/webpack-react-typescript-bug
2. Install deps with `npm install`
3. Run `npm start`
4. Go to http://localhost:8080
5. Change something in i.e. `src/components/Hello.tsx`

The initial generated index.html looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

And after at least 1 webpack dev server watch tour and build:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use both `html-webpack-plugin` and `copy-webpack-plugin` to create an `index.html` in the `dist` directory.

```
plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {from: 'index.html'},
    ], {
        copyUnmodified: true
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: 'index.html'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackIncludeAssetsPlugin({
        assets: [], append: false, hash: true
    })
]
```

You don't need `copy-webpack-plugin` for this as the `html-webpack-plugin` already generates the `index.html` and automatically puts it in the `dist` directory. Despite that it's not needed, it actually causes problems with hot reloading, because `webpack-dev-server` thinks that the new `index.html` is the copied one, instead of the generated one. To see why this is happening you can take a look at the output after recompiling.

**with copy plugin**

```
                                   Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
                               bundle.js    1.06 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
    0.135a3b584db27942bf6f.hot-update.js    1.36 kB       0  [emitted]         main
    135a3b584db27942bf6f.hot-update.json   43 bytes          [emitted]
                           bundle.js.map    1.26 MB       0  [emitted]         main
0.135a3b584db27942bf6f.hot-update.js.map  894 bytes       0  [emitted]         main
                              index.html  146 bytes          [emitted]
```

**without copy plugin**

```
                                   Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
                               bundle.js    1.06 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
    0.135a3b584db27942bf6f.hot-update.js    1.36 kB       0  [emitted]         main
    135a3b584db27942bf6f.hot-update.json   43 bytes          [emitted]
                           bundle.js.map    1.26 MB       0  [emitted]         main
0.135a3b584db27942bf6f.hot-update.js.map  894 bytes       0  [emitted]         main
```

The difference is that with the copy plugin you emit a new `index.html`, which is just the copied one, because the `html-webpack-plugin` didn't see any changes and therefore didn't emit a new one. Hence `webpack-dev-server` serves this newly emitted `index.html`.

Note: If you had used a hash in your filename (e.g. `bundle.[hash].js`) it would have worked, because it emits a new `index.html` after every recompilation. Regardless, it's not a good idea to have conflicting plugins.

Comment: Thank You very much! It's so logical that i feel embarrassed i haven't figured it out by myself. But im glad You did. Thanks again!